# Analogues of xlErrorHandler for Word/Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

Does anyone know about any handlers for user breaks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> for Word/Access VBA?

There is very useful handler `Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler` for Excel, but I need to handle user breaks in Access and Word.

Any suggestions?

Comment: With Access, you can compile to an ACCDE and not worry about this - the user will not have programmatic access to the IDE at that point. Let me know if this is what you are looking for and I can post this as an answer - I'm not sure if you are intending to capture/act on them or just prevent it from messing up execution.

Comment: Well, my temporary solution is:
 `#If HostProject = "Access" Then
        ChangeProperty "AllowSpecialKeys", dbBoolean, False  
    #ElseIf HostProject = "Word" Then  
        Application.EnableCancelKey = wdCancelDisabled
    #Else
        Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    #End If`

I just disable user break, but really need a solution of handling breaks like in Excel via `xlErrorHandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Word, you could try

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = wdCancelInterrupt
```

For Access, I'm not aware of an equivalent. I don't think one is directly provided.

A way to force the code to check for user events would be to add the line

```
Application. DoEvents
```

inside the loop. Since this line will slow down the code, it should be executed every *n* iterations.

Comment: Well, I just use `Application.EnableCancelKey = wdCancelDisabled` for Word and some handmade fuction for allowing special keys for Access, but this is not a complete solution. I need to do some actions on user breaks, not only suppress them.

Comment: Just curious, what happens on repeatedly pressing escape? In the worst case, try this. Add a line `Application.DoEvents` inside your loop. That would slow it down so you may want to execute that every 100 iterations or so, but that'll pause loop execution to see if Esc etc. is pressed. Works for Excel and might work here as well.

Comment: I want to catch the Ctrl+Break user break. Excel handler allows me to do this, but there are no such handlers in Word and Access. `Do events` will not help because I don't want to let user to look into the code.

Comment: That's ok. Because you can password protect your modules to prevent accidental opening of the editor